# Style Filter for Mapbox: attribute not set

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am not sure if I am just blind, but. In Mapbox you can filter your dataset.
So what I want is to display all lines of a given class, that have a certain attribute NOT set. I see options for `Exists`, `Is` and `Is Not`. But there is no `Does not exist`, right? Is there a way to define that? Or do I have to do that when exporting my dataset beforehand?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to wrap your expression in the [logical negation operator](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#):

```
["!",{{your expression here}}]
```

In Mapbox Studio, after creating the filter, you can switch from the UI editor to the JSON editor at the bottom of the pane:

[image]